# onRequestPermissionsResult overrides nothing error after updating Gradle - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am having this issue after updating the flutter/dart/Gradle. This is the code that gets displayed, also i added all the permissions required.

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-4.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (124, 1): Class 'FlutterLocationService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-4.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (258, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.
Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.